# I want to get diff Controls Id through java script?? as any control can be added on form script will return the type of Control and its ID

Tags: javascript

I want to get diff Controls Id through java script??any control can be added by user on form java script will return the type of Control for ex textbox,label and its ID

Answer (score 1):

By controls, I'm assuming you mean form input controls. To get the id of an element, you can call `.getAttribute('id')` on an object. To get the type of a form element, access the 'type` attribute.

For example, if you want the `id` attribute and type of an input in the first form on a page, where the input has the `name` attribute "title":

```
var titleInput = document.forms[0].getElementsByName('title')[0];
alert("id = '" + titleInput.getAttribute('id') + "'\ntype = '" = titleInput.type + "'");
```